# Mixing externalGraphic and default point renderer on VectorLayer

Tags: openlayers-2

Is it possible to mix externalgraphics and the default point renderer for vector layers? I haven't been able to find an example that does this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

I find this article very helpful on styling: http://docs.openlayers.org/library/feature_styling.html

You will want to look at the section on Rule Based Styling. In particular note this line: "The symbolizers inside rules do not have to be complete symbolizers, because they extend the default symbolizer passed with the constructor of OpenLayers.Style or OpenLayers.StyleMap."